# The best way to create a machine learning model/neural network that automatically searches for efficient available time slots in an employee's agenda

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, classification

For an assignment I need to work out how to incorporate machine learning techniques/neural networks into automatic appointment planning.

The algorithm needs to be able to be able to check all open time slots in an employee's agenda and return the open time slot that will be the most efficient choice, taking mainly location and distance to the previous and next appointment into account.

This might be interesting for large companies with loads of employees but in my case its quite silly since there are just about 20 agenda's to worry about. I don't actually need to create the solution I just need to present how it would be done. I did actually create planning software that can automatically search for efficient available time slots, but I did this using a match variable to calculate the fit of each time slot.

What I have thought of so far is a simple supervised classification model that is trained on dummy time slots with a boolean as label which will indicate if the time slot is a good fit or not.
Each of these time slots would be a vector containing the available time, time needed for the appointment and travel time to and from the appointment.

The solution above would probably function the same as the solution with a match calculation using a threshold to determine the output.

I could also turn it into a regression model, using the match calculation to train the model but that would probably function exactly the same as match calculation but instead of calculation it uses prediction.

Then I thought of neural networks, which probably could be used to tackle this problem but I have no clue as to how you would go about creating a neural network for this problem.

If anyone has some idea's or suggestions I'd be very grateful.

Comment: This is an *optimization* task, not a *statistical* or *machine learning* one. There are tons of common scheduling optimization algorithms. Why do you want to use ML/NNs here?

Comment: I dont, but the assignment is to find out how it could be applied here

Comment: sounds more interesting to consider (predicting) changes in calendar schedules which could affect the result of the optimal match